# How to use spark-submit's --properties-file option to launch Spark application in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm starting a project using Spark developed with Scala and IntelliJ IDE.

I was wondering how to set `-- properties-file` with specific configuration of Spark in IntelliJ configuration.

I'm reading configuration like this `"param1" -> sc.getConf.get("param1")`

When I execute Spark job from command line works like a charm:
`/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "com.class.main" --master local --properties-file properties.conf ./target/scala-2.11/main.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`

The problem is when I execute job using IntelliJ Run Configuration using `VM Options`:

1. I succeed with `--master` param as `-Dspark.master=local`
2. I succeed with `--conf` params as `-Dspark.param1=value1`
3. I **failed** with `--properties-file`

Can anyone point me at the right way to set this up?

Comment: In my "properties-file": `spark.param1 value1` and is placed in root of the project at the same level of `build.sbt`

Answer (score 1):

I **don't** think it's possible to use `--properties-file` to launch a Spark application from within IntelliJ IDEA.

`spark-submit` is the shell script to submit Spark application for execution and does few extra things before it creates a proper submission environment for the Spark application.

You can however mimic the behaviour of `--properties-file` by leveraging `conf/spark-defaults.conf` that a Spark application loads by default.

You could create a `conf/spark-defaults.conf` under `src/test/resources` (or `src/main/resources`) with the content of `properties.conf`. That is *supposed* to work.

Comment: This didnt work for me. Ultimately, I resorted to using VM options and passing all arguments in there using -D....

Comment: @datmannz Where did you save the properties file? What's the build tool you use? If sbt, save the file in `src/main/resources/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. It heavily depends on where you start a Spark app.

Comment: OP, Did you get this to work ? I am trying to but no luck yet ! @JacekLaskowski Any help appreciated !

Comment: @KarthikJ Can you describe the steps you do and what error you see? Use gist.github.com or something that allows for a longer answer (as a comment).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski https://gist.github.com/karthik-arris/c1c1b974406b5a403c8148a928a15869

Comment: Agreed, doesn't seem to work in the way Jacek has described. Using Spark 2.4.5.